# Increasing temperatures means

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, error

I saw the following sentence in a magazine. To my surprise, the plural subject "increasing temperatures" is paired with the singular verb "means." Is it a typo or a correct usage? Is this a way to present the temperatures as a unit?

> Increasing temperatures **means** water evaporates more quickly. The excess moisture in the air leads to intense periods of rain over a short amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct. It means something like:

> **The presence of** increasing temperatures means water evaporates more quickly.

In other words, when we have increasing temperatures, it means water evaporates more quickly. To treat "mean" as a plural verb would mean *each temperature means something*, which is not the case. The combined state of all the temperatures rising *means* something.

Comment: Is it OK to say "These books **is** poor" meaning that **The condition of** these books is poor"?

Comment: The original sentence sounds a bit awkward to me, although I agree you can make the case it refers to increasing temperatures as a single phenomenon. "These books is" sounds wrong, because it's not describing a single thing; it's the conditions of several books.

Comment: If "these books" refers to a set of books sold as a unit, could it be considered "a single thing"?

Comment: @Apollyon As StuartF picked up on, what I meant by "condition of" is "phenomenon of" or "the fact that we have", not "the state of repair of". I've also added more to my answer. Does that clarify?

Comment: @gotube Thank you. I think your idea is on the right track, although I think the "books" example seems to call for a more fine-tuned treatment. Couldn't we say, for example, "The fact that we have these boring books **means** that the author must be a boring man"? If it's  OK, how do we rule out "These boring books **means** that the author is a boring man"?

Comment: If you're talking about "boring books" in general, then yes, it can refer to "the presence of boring books". This sentence: "*Boring books means you're a boring person*" could be used as a general measure of whether someone is boring based on their book collection. But if you specify which books, as in your last sentence above (or which temperatures, as in your original question), the verb must be plural.

Answer (score 0):

The subject of the verb "means" is the gerund "increasing", and gerunds are singular.

This is an interesting case since the verb form depends on whether the -ing word is treated as a gerund/participle (with "temperatures" being the object of the gerund) Or if the -ing word is an adjective.  Compare:

> Freezing apples is a good way to preserve them until spring.

> Freezing days are common in winter.

Comment: But the source article is about climate change, and the OP sentence is about temperatures which are increasing.

Comment: Surely "increasing" is modifying the noun "temperatures", as in "smoking embers are a sign of fire"; you seem to be suggesting that "temperatures" is the object and "smoking" the subject, as in "smoking cigarettes is bad for you", but I don't think that's right. The two structures are different.